# React Native : How to implement a Text Area with Mentions very similar to Facebook Comment?

Tags: ios, react-native, uitextview

How to implement a Text Area with Mentions very similar to Facebook Comment for react native. Facebook allow user to tag a person(by looking up in server) and will show the name in the text field and user can continue typing.

Is there a plugin already available or do I have to create a plugin and if thats the case which UI component in IOS I have to look ?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that with [react-native-mention](https://github.com/harshq/react-native-mentions) component. I have not tried this component but I believe this will solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks, At a first look it looks like the plugin replacing the mentions with a uniqueue, similar to what twitter is doing. But I prefer something similar to Facebook which shows the name itself. But This is certainly helpful and a starting point If I am creating a plugin.

Comment: But If I could get something similar to Facebook it will be much helpful, Thats why I am keeping my question open.

Comment: I am also looking for the similar solution.

Comment: You can achieve it with [react-native-mentions](https://github.com/harshq/react-native-mentions) & [react-native-parsed-text](https://github.com/taskrabbit/react-native-parsed-text)

Comment: Both npm is not working with  react native web.